# dijit.form.Combobox show label Instead of value

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I've a `dijit.form.Combobox` field which uses a `ItemFileReadStore` to pull Its data.
Teh ItemFileReadStore has two attribute per Item `value` which will be used for form submission , generally Unique Integers and `label` which is Human Understandable String.
In ComboBox HTML I've done `searchAttr="value" labelAttr="label"`
When the ComboBox Shows the list it uses teh label Attribute.
But When the User selects one of the Item it shows the value of that Item.

What I want is , The value Attribute will Still be used for Form Submission. But the User will always see the label in the combobox Control.

[alt text http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/6660/dijitcombo.jpg](http://img822.imageshack.us/img822/6660/dijitcombo.jpg)

e.g. I Want to Show The Label for value 3 (Admin) instead of 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [FilteringSelect](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect) instead of [Combobox](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dijit/form/ComboBox).

Note: ComboBox only has a single value that matches what is displayed while FilteringSelect  incorporates a hidden value that corresponds to the displayed value.

Comment: Try jQuery if you can?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following.

```
var cmbObject = Registry.byId('combo dojo id'); var id =
cmbObject.item.<Code Property>;
```

You should check if item is null.